# Is there an easy way to convert an image to QR code using python?

Tags: python, qr-code

I wrote a code that creating a QR code image that contain a string.
I wonder if is there any simple way to convert an image to QR code.

this is the implementation so far:

```
 from PIL import
 import qrcode

 def creatig_qr_code():

    qr = qrcode.make(
         "info_to_print"
    )

    qr.save('Element.png')
```

Comment: You may be able to convert the image to a `base64` encoded string and then convert that string to QR code

Comment: What do you mean by "convert" an image? Read an existing image elsewhere, interpret it (read text I assume?) and then represent it as another image - but this time its a QR code containing the interpreted text? Or, as the others are assuming - you want it represented as an encoded string?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
import base64
import qrcode


with open("yourimage_path", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
qr = qrcode.QRCode()
qr.add_data(encoded_string)
qr.make()
```

and then save, or do whatever you want with the qr.

### EDIT

The qrcode dimensions has to match the dimensions of the image you are trying to encode. Choosing a too tiny dimension will result in `DataOverflowError`.

Change the qr code instantiation `qr = qrcode.QRCode()` with:

```
qr = qrcode.QRCode(version={"correct version"}, error_correction=qrcode.constants.{"correct error correction type"})
```

choosing the values that fits you necessity from a table like [this](https://blog.qr4.nl/page/QR-Code-Data-Capacity.aspx)

Comment: I think maybe some libraries are missing, I have errors in many lines which are not exist

Comment: What do you mean? Paste the error you are getting

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e174701\OneDrive - Applied Materials\Desktop\QRCODE\draft.py", line 12, in <module>
    qr.make()
  File "C:\Users\e174701\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\qrcode\main.py", line 103, in make
    self.best_fit(start=self.version)
  File "C:\Users\e174701\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\qrcode\main.py", line 180, in best_fit
    raise exceptions.DataOverflowError()
qrcode.exceptions.DataOverflowError